# What's the difference between streaming mappings and coherent mapping in DMA

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, intel, dma, realtek

According to Linux Device Drivers book author says something like: one have to make sure that DMA address mapping range between Operating system and The hardware should be equal

> The first question that must be answered before attempting DMA is where the given device is
> capable of such an operation on the current host

From Kernel.org it says
first step for The setup for streaming mappings is performed via a call to

```
        int dma_set_mask(struct device *dev, u64 mask);
```

And first step for DMA coherent mapping/consistent allocations is performed via a call

```
       to dma_set_coherent_mask()
```

In E1000E driver and also in RealTek drivers do both because they use this function call in probe function of pci driver

```
       dma_set_mask_and_coherent
```

Which is for both streaming and coherent mapping informing kernel the bit mask supported by hardware `64`

This is how RealTek Device driver enables both DMA mappings

```
      dma_alloc_coherent(&pdev->dev, R8169_RX_RING_BYTES,
                     &tp->RxPhyAddr, GFP_KERNEL);
```

inside open function of net_device

And for streaming DMA mapping this used

```
     alloc_pages_node  // allocating Kernel page for DMA
     dma_map_page(d, data, 0, R8169_RX_BUF_SIZE, DMA_FROM_DEVICE); //Enabling Streaming mappingg?
```

also in open function

My question is why two mappings for DMA,  why real drivers use both Streaming and Coherent mappings?

Like in RealTek device it just use single page streaming mappings plus coherent mapping so basically its connecting Rx Descriptor Array represented by pointer with Coherent mapping and Page streaming mapping connected to an array which it calls Rx_databuff[256U] of type `page *`

Comment: The descriptors are mapped coherently so that they can be accessed by the CPU and the device DMA bus master at the same time.

Comment: Although the Rx buffers linked to by the Rx descriptor array use streaming mappings and are synced to the device most of the time (and only synced to the CPU while received data is being copied to a socket buffer), streaming mappings are considered less expensive to set up than coherent mappings, so streaming mappings should be preferred over coherent mappings where possible.

Comment: @IanAbbott thanks. I'll understand, for the coherent case,  the kernel allocates some pages and sets up page table entries for DMA. To make it coherent, does the kernel set the memory attributes in the page table so that the coherency if maintained (by cache snooping) by the interconnect? I'm not 100% sure my understanding is correct.